# Vanilla js how to check if html element exists before executing script

Tags: javascript, async-await, wait

hey I am trying to figure out how to make my script wait with executing a part of it while an element is loading in, but currently it mostly just passes it, and does not wait for it.
What is the best way to do that in vanilla js?

this is the code

```
this.heading = document.getElementById("heading");
```

that i want it to wait or repeat checking until the heading is there for sure every time

Thank you

Comment: How does it load in?

Comment: i have a html file that loads into the index by hash and this script does not wait for it to load all of the code can be seen here: https://github.com/benonymus/vanilla-js-mvc-with-routing2

Comment: This sounds like a job for Mutation Observer

Comment: IMHO the suggestion made by @JosanIracheta is the best and more elegant solution to this problem. An example can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can repeatedly check for the heading and then do something with it once it is obtained like this.

```
var heading;

function getHeading() {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (heading = document.getElementById('heading')) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            console.log(heading);
            // do some stuff here with your heading
        }
    }, 100);  // 100 represents how often the script checks for existence of heading in ms
}

getHeading();
```

Comment: @JonasWilms: what would be the right way to do it, in the case of a page in a third-party website?

Answer (score 2):

Do this after you load in your template. Checking repeatedly if something has happened (polling) is usually a bad idea. This should happen **because** the template loaded. In your case it looks like that would be in `goToRoute`:

```
goToRoute: function (htmlName) {
    (function(scope) { 
        var url = 'views/' + htmlName,
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                scope.rootElem.innerHTML = this.responseText;

                // Now it's ready

            }
        };
        xhttp.open('GET', url, true);
        xhttp.send();
    })(this);
}
```

It might not make sense to put the specific code you're thinking about into `goToRoute`; to make it more versatile you could think about making `goToRoute` accept a callback parameter, or using events.

Comment: Yes. Definetly. Now just a small example of what you mean with your last sentence and the answer is upvoteworthy :)

Comment: yes this seems interesting but then how do i keep the mvc intact?